# How to check a checkbox if a function return true?

Tags: angular

I have a component which contains some checkboxes, and I need to check some of them if a function returns me true.
I know that I can't call a function with *ngIf because angular call it infinitely.
I would like to do something like :

```
<div *ngIf="this.chkFamilles(f.id); then thenBlock else elseBlock"></div>
          <ng-template #thenBlock>
            <input type="checkbox" checked class="form-check-input" name="chkFamilles" id="{{f.id}}">
            <label for="{{f.id}}">{{ f.nom }}</label>
          </ng-template>
          <ng-template #elseBlock>
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="chkFamilles" id="{{f.id}}">
            <label for="{{f.id}}">{{ f.nom }}</label>
          </ng-template>
```

This is my HTML formular :

```
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onUpdateVariante(f.value)">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6" *ngIf="this.listAccessoires">
          <label class="control-label">Accessoire</label>
          <select required="true" name="accessoire" class="form-control" id="selectAccessoire" *ngIf="this.listAccessoires">
            <option *ngFor="let a of this.listAccessoires" value={{a.id}}>{{a.nom}}</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label class="control-label">Familles</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6" *ngFor="let f of this.listFamilles">
          <div *ngIf="this.chkFamilles(f.id); then thenBlock else elseBlock"></div>
          <ng-template #thenBlock>
            <input type="checkbox" checked class="form-check-input" name="chkFamilles" id="{{f.id}}">
            <label for="{{f.id}}">{{ f.nom }}</label>
          </ng-template>
          <ng-template #elseBlock>
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="chkFamilles" id="{{f.id}}">
            <label for="{{f.id}}">{{ f.nom }}</label>
          </ng-template>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Save</button>
        </div>
      </form>
```

And this is my function chkFamilles() :

```
chkFamilles(idFamille : number): boolean{
    console.log("test");
    this.serviceQualif.getQualificationsByIdOperateurAndIdAccessoire(this.idOperateur, 2).subscribe(data =>{
      data.map((competence) =>{
        if(competence.famille.id == idFamille){
          return true;
          console.log("test");
        }
      })
    });
    return false;
  }
```

If somebody has a solution, it will be helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this.
`<input type="checkbox" [checked]="this.chkFamilles(f.id)" class="form-check-input" name="chkFamilles" id="{{f.id}}"/>`

let me know if you have any doubt.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @piyush, but thats like what I've already done. And it make an infinite call so it doesn't work.

Comment: If you are calling method on checked attribute of input, I don't think it will make infinite call. I have used this approach earlier also.

Comment: I don't know why but for me, it make an infinite call and my app stop working.

Comment: In that case can you please provide sample on stackblitz.com ?

Comment: But I have multiple API calls in my component, how can I do to avoid all those calls ?

Comment: `this.serviceQualif.getQualificationsByIdOperateurAndIdAccessoire(this.idOperateur, 2)`

This api call I will suggest you to do in another method and in this method check `competence.famille.id == idFamille` only using `map` method.

Comment: sorry I'm new in Angular, but if I do this, I put the value returned by this.serviceQualif.getQualificationsByIdOperateurAndIdAccessoire(this.idOperateur, 2) in a variable, but if I reused it , it's always undefined.